# Prevent window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open from being overriden in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, overriding

Im trying to make custom window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype function and prevent it from being overriden. This is my code, but it it still easily lets me change the function later. What am I doing wrong?

```
Object.defineProperty(window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open', {
  writeable: false,
  value: function() {
    console.log('Custom function here');
  }
});

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = null; //Works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the property before defining it:

```
delete XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
```